# Burn remote data on to a disc

Tags: linux, remote, iso, burning

I have an ISO image in another system which I need to burn on my system. I can copy that image to my system using SCP and then do burning. But I would like to know, whether I can directly burn the remote data(image here) to the dvd? Both the systems have GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over both systems, you could share the data with NFS, mount it on your system, and burn your image just as you would if the data was local.

There's also [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), which lets you mount a remote machine's filesystem using ssh as the data bearer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yeah, this is one method that I can use. I would also like to know whether we can transfer the data block by block that can directly write into the dvd?? Because, ultimately the data stored onto the disks are only blocks. So, it would be great if only blocks are transfered? Is there any method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

If you can ssh to the system where the ISO file resides you can do this:

```
ssh syswithiso 'cat /path/to/file.iso' | growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=/dev/fd/0
```

**NOTE:** The /dev/fd/0 is the file descriptor for STDIN.

#### References

- [Hard Drive Cloning in Linux](http://radagast.ca/linux/hard_drive_cloning_in_linux.html)

Comment: Thanks sim for your reply. I would be very much thankful if you can answer my question in the above comment.

Comment: The method in my answer does exactly what you asked for. Do you not understand what or how it is doing this?

Comment: SSH connection will transfer the data block by block?? If so then one more question I have, If you don't mind, why we need protocols like SCSI, FCoE for sending the block data. Why don't we use ssh?? To my knowledge, SCSI and FCoE are used for sending block data. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry you were referring to the comment on @Flup's answer, his answer shows below mine when I view this page. I see what you're asking about regarding block for block. In general the idea of "block for block" doesn't work because of how TCP/IP works, the packets are not sent in order, but they are reassembled into their original order after they're received. So it's a bit of a misnomer that the data is being sent exactly as it is on the disk over the network.

Comment: I think you're getting confused on the concepts of iSCSI and FCoE in what they do when implemented physically on a box and their implementations when going over Ethernet. http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/FCoE-Fibre-Channel-over-Ethernet

Comment: That links states the following: "...FCoE uses a lossless Ethernet fabric and its own frame format. It retains Fibre Channel’s device communications but substitutes high-speed Ethernet links for Fibre Channel links between devices..."